# AVR Flash Writing Error

Tags: avr, avrdude

Got a very strange error while trying to write to ATmega128. Below are the results for 3 cases (using different software but the same USBASP programmer and the same HEX file)

- **Case 1 : AVRDUDESS 2.3**: I am able to write a program 236 bytes in size. However anything bigger than 255 bytes gives the following error

> avrdude.exe: verifying ... avrdude.exe: verification error, first
>   mismatch at byte 0x0100
>                0xff != 0xf1 avrdude.exe: verification error; content mismatch
>
> avrdude.exe done.  Thank you.

- **Case 2 : Extreme Burner AVR v 1.4 :** Does not support Atmega128
- **Case 3 : AVR8 Burn-O-Mat v2 :** able to program the same hex file without any issue

Can't figure out why one software would give an error while the other one works just fine when they both are using avrdude in the background

Comment: Can you find the avrdude command line for cases 1 and 3?  Are they using the same version of avrdude?  Are you sure you successfully programmed **and verified** in case 3?  Does the problem occur with a different atmega chip?

Comment: I have the same problem but haven't tested with Burn-O-Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did get around to checking the command line syntax used by avrdude.

However as mentioned, burn-o-mat worked without any issues.